# Deserialize property from JSON twice?

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

I have a weird problem:

I have a class A which contains a subclass B. class A is rather complex and changes frequently. I do need only a small fraction of the properties of class A and a complete json representation of class B, to pass it on to a different service.

This looks like this

```
[DataContact]
public class A 
{
    [DataMember]
    public B Inner {get; set;}
}

[DataContact]
public class B 
{
    [DataMember]
    public int SomeThing {get; set;}
}
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
[DataContact]
public class ADesired
{
    [DataMember]
    public B Inner {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string InnerAsJsonString {get; set;}
}
```

I tried the most obvious ideas (e.g. a Jsonproperty which refers to the same name, but NewtonSoft.Json refusses to make this work)

What I have tried so far:

1. JsonConverter, did not work at all.
2. JsonProperties:

   ```
   [DataContact]
   public class ADesired
   {
       [JsonProperty("Source")]
       public B Inner {get; set;}

       [JsonProperty("Source")]
       public string InnerAsJsonString {get; set;}
   }
   ```

   Which does not work at runtime, since the reference to the same property is detected.
3. Nuclear option: Just deserialize the string twice in the controller, but this feels just wrong.

Comment: Can you share what have you tried ?

Comment: @Arash Done, see above

Comment: @ChristianSauer I had to read the first paragraph a few times until I understood what you mean. I've edited it, please see if my edit is correct.

Comment: @Rotem I believe it's the other way around. Class B has some properties, but the JSON that gets deserialized into B has more content than gets deserialized. Therefore deserialization loses information, and OP would like to preserve that lost info.

Comment: @Amis, this is correct. Thx!

Comment: @ChristianSauer Kindly roll back my edit and clarify it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to serialize it in the class

```
[DataContact]
public class ADesired
{
    [DataMember]
    public B Inner {get; set;}
    public string InnerAsJsonString => Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Inner);
}
```

Comment: Hi, unfurtonately Inner only captures a fraction of the attributes of the real json object, but I need the whole json to be forwared

Comment: @ChristianSauer How is this different than what you called `ADesired` in the OP?

Comment: Can't you do it the other way around - let InnerAsJsonString be the declared DataMember, and deserialize to Inner in the setter for InnerAsJsonString?

Comment: @MKloster  Yes, that works. Only drawback: I have to check validation errors etc. myself. Therefore I would have liked the json-string as the special case.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about performance, you could use JObject as the Json-Property type.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

[DatanContract]
public class ADesired
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public B Inner { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string InnerJson { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(nameof(Inner))
    public JObject JInner
    {
        get => JObject.FromObject(Inner);
        set { Inner = value.ToObject<B>(); InnerJson = value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

That way when deserializing, the actual json is saved as `InnerJson` and what can be, is deserialized into `Inner`, and when serializing back, whatever is in `Inner` will get serialized.